# tar ssh not working properly

Tags: php, linux, ssh, tar

I'm trying to compress a directory ( /home/8003/ ) to a tar file. I'm using PHP script.

```
    $filename = hash("crc32", date('Y-m-d-H-i-s',$laikas ) ).".tar.gz";
    $do = "tar -zcvf  /var/www/backups/".$sd[0]['port']."/".$filename." /home/".$sd[0]['port']."/*"; // $sd[0]['port'] is equal to 8003, that directory exist
    $ssh->SendCommand($do);
```

Everything works, but compressed .tar.gz file is only 20 bytes size and empty. When i do the same command on putty, it is about 1.5 mb size and works fine. DEBUG of $do:

```
tar -zcvf /var/www/backups/8003/1b96a89f.tar.gz /home/8003/*
```

Comment: Have you checked access rights? Is this run in a web server?

Comment: Yes, all folders permissions set to 0777, this is running in web server (remote).

Comment: What does the tar files contents looks like (i.e. `tar -tf /var/www/backups/8003/1b96a89f.tar.gz`)?

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in `/home/8003/*` is probably not being expanded. Try omitting it, e. g.

```
$do = "tar -zcvf  /var/www/backups/".$sd[0]['port']."/".$filename." /home/".$sd[0]['port'];
```